# Sub-additivity in a probability space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am proving th generalization of sub-additivity in probability. And i cant proceed to the next step because i cant show that this is true: $P( \bigcup A_i - \bigcup B_i )= P( \bigcup A_i) - P( \bigcup B_i)$. I cant show how this is an immediate equality?

Comment: What you mention is true under condition that $\cup B_i\subseteq\cup A_i$.

Comment: Yes @drhab. I have no idea how to show the equality above

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two events such that $A\subseteq B$. Then
$$
\Pr(B\setminus A)=\Pr(B)-\Pr(A)
$$
since $B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$, where $A$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint sets.

If $B\subseteq A$, then $\Pr(B\setminus A)=0$.

Comment: This proof is true. But it wont apply under the assumptions given. You have unions of set.

Comment: @mogs I don't think that it matters. A union of sets is a set. Denote $A=\bigcup A_i$ and $B=\bigcup B_i$.

Comment: $ \bigcup (A_i - B_i)$ and $ \bigcup B_i $ are not disjoint.

Comment: @mogs Suppose that $\bigcup B_i\subseteq\bigcup A_i$. Then
$\bigcup A_i=(\bigcup B_i)\cup((\bigcup A_i)\setminus(\bigcup B_i))$, where $\bigcup B_i$ and $(\bigcup A_i)\setminus(\bigcup B_i)$ are disjoint sets. Thus, $\Pr(\bigcup A_i)=\Pr(\bigcup B_i)+\Pr((\bigcup A_i)\setminus(\bigcup B_i))$.

Comment: That is why i am not convinced. Since, these sets are not always disjoint. For example, if the intersection of $B_i's$ is in the intersection of $A_i's$ @v.c

Comment: @mogs Are you convinced that if $A$ and $B$ are two sets such that $A\subseteq B$, then $A$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint sets?

Comment: There's a missing link

Comment: Thanks @v.c i get it already...

Comment: @mogs You're welcome!